# ORDEM DE EXECUCAO VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue.js-2, vuetify

Boa tarde,

Srs.

Usando o vue com lib e nao como framework, tenho duas funcoes que fazem requisicoes para dois endpoints, onde o primeiro eu consigo um token e na segunda, eu preciso passar o token para fazer a requisição.
Coloquei na mounted, minha funcao que recebe o token. até aí ok.
O problema está quando eu tento fazer a segunda chamada, se eu colocar um botao para fazer a requisição, tudo ocorre bem, contudo, eu gostaria que no carregamento da página, ambas acontecessem, porem uma depende da outra e a segunda chamada sempre da erro.

Eu poderia encadear dois axios numa funcao (nao sei como fazer isso) e também poderia fazer com que de alguma forma, a segunda chamada só ocorresse quando a primeira chamada (token) estivesse concluido.

Como devo proceder?

Obrigado!!

```js
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
        teste:'',
        oauthToken:'',
        gwDevAppKey:'',
        agenciaBeneficiario:'452',
        contaBeneficiario:'123873',
        indicadorSituacao:'B',
        indice:'300',
        codigoEstadoTituloCobranca:'7',
        dataInicioMovimento:'04.09.2020',
        dataFimMovimento:'09.09.2020',
  }),
    created: function(){
        //this.getOauthToken();
    
    },
    
    computed:{
        getToken(){
            return this.oauthToken;
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.getBoletos();
        
    },
  
    methods: {
        getOauthToken(){
            axios({method: 'post',url:'https://oauth.sandbox.bb.com.br/oauth/token?',
            headers: {
                ContentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization":'',
                "Accept":"*/*"
            }, 
            data: {
                grant_type: "client_credentials",
                scope: "cobrancas.boletos-info cobrancas.boletos-requisicao"
            }
            }).then(response => {
                this.oauthToken=response.data.token_type+' '+response.data.access_token;
                console.log(this.oauthToken)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        getBoletos(){
            let agenciaBeneficiario=this.agenciaBeneficiario;
            let contaBeneficiario=this.contaBeneficiario;
            let indicadorSituacao=this.indicadorSituacao;
            let indice=this.indice;
            let codigoEstadoTituloCobranca=this.codigoEstadoTituloCobranca;
            let dataInicioMovimento=this.dataInicioMovimento;
            let dataFimMovimento=this.dataFimMovimento;
            let gwDevAppKey=this.gwDevAppKey;
            let params='&agenciaBeneficiario='+agenciaBeneficiario+'&contaBeneficiario='+contaBeneficiario+'&indicadorSituacao='+indicadorSituacao+'&indice='+indice+'&codigoEstadoTituloCobranca='+codigoEstadoTituloCobranca+'&dataInicioMovimento='+dataInicioMovimento+'&dataFimMovimento='+dataFimMovimento;
            console.log(params);
            axios({method: 'post',url:'https://oauth.sandbox.bb.com.br/oauth/token?',
            headers: {
                ContentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization":'',
                "Accept":"*/*"
            }, 
            data: {
                grant_type: "client_credentials",
                scope: "cobrancas.boletos-info cobrancas.boletos-requisicao"
            }
            }).then(response => {
                this.oauthToken=response.data.token_type+' '+response.data.access_token;
                console.log(this.oauthToken)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            axios({method: 'get',url:'https://api.sandbox.bb.com.br/cobrancas/v1/boletos?'+'gw-dev-app-key='+gwDevAppKey+params,
            headers: {
                ContentType:"application/json",
                "Authorization":this.oauthToken,
                "Accept":"*/*"
            }, 
            data: {

            }
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                console.log('token:'+this.oauthToken)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                console.log('token:'+this.oauthToken)
            });
        }
        
    },
    
    })
  </script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>BOLETOS ONLINE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-spinning-spinners/1.1.0/load4.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.loading:before { font-size: 5px; }
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="app" data-app>
    <v-row class="text-center" width="100%">
      <v-col cols="12">
        <h2 style="text-align:center" class="font-weight-light mb-2 center">    REGISTRAR MANIFESTACAO DEVOLUCAO TOTAL</h2>
            <div>   
                <v-alert type="error">DIV ERROR</v-alert>
            </div>
                <v-card-text>
                    <v-row>
    
                    </v-row>
                    <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation>
                        <v-col cols="12" sm="2">
                            <v-container fluid>
                                <v-text-field required label="Filial" v-model="teste" placeholder="Ex:1,3,6" outlined dense required></v-text-field>
                            </v-container>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-form>
                    <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn @click="">CANCELAR</v-btn>
                    <v-btn @click="getBoletos()">SALVAR</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

você deve usar o `await` para esperar a primeira promise que traz o token e só então realizará a segunda request, e para isso você deve declarar o mounted como [assíncrono](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas), por exemplo

```
async mounted() {
      await this.getOauthToken();
      await this.getBoletos();
        
    },
```

Comment: Achei uma boa, faz sentido, mas nao deu certo :/

Comment: o que aconteceu? também notei que você está buscando o token duas vezes, não faz sentido fazer essa request que busca o token duas vezes

Comment: Simplesmente me retornou um "bad request", pois o authorization no meu header da requisição está em branco. Sobre realizar duas vezes, é pq estava testando, somente.

Comment: Coloquei a minha funcao getBoletos() dentro do .then(response)e no mounted eu acho só a funcao getOauthToekn().
Contudo, nao achei "elegante" e nao sei se é a melhor prática. com await e assync me pareceu mais interessante e realmente gostaria que funcionasse assim.